# django on docker - https with letsencrypt

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I have implemented django on docker deployment process using below tutorial.
https://github.com/testdrivenio/django-on-docker

I'm using ubuntu 18 server, Installed docker and docker-compose. I'm trying to integrate  https with letsencrypt for my website. How to integrate the https with letsencrypt using existing docker compose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a docker image of nginx web server to integrate https with your existing docker using a simple configuration:

Refer: https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried but no luck with existing configuration.

Comment: Have you gone through that link? It has letsencrypt integration.